# How to return a html in spring boot controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm really new to spring boot, this is my first time using it, I don't want to, but I have to, and I'm stuck. I have a spring boot app that displays elements of a database

```
@GetMapping
public List<Movie> getMovies(){
    return movieService.getMovies();
}
```

I have this GetMapping, and when I load the page, it displays the element of the database, in JSON format, like this:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Django","releaseDate":"2012-12-12","rating":8.4},{"id":2,"title":"Pulp Fiction","releaseDate":"1994-04-13","rating":8.9}]
```

How should I edit the GetMapping to returnl a html file, in which I display this data? Also, how should I use the html to use the getMovies function?

Comment: As duffymo mentioned, also read through Thymeleaf and its dependency to manipulate and render your data to the view (html) using Spring Boot's Controller class using `@Controller` annotation. Try this - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/crud-application-thymeleaf/

Comment: Thank you @AjayKumar ,this link helped a lot, it actually solved my problem. I'll look into thymeleaf a bit more, this is truly a usefull tool.

Comment: Great. Welcome aboard. Keep posting questions and keep learning.

Answer (score 3):

"Don't want to"?  It's a great framework.  You'll learn something.

The controller is mapped to a URL with an HTTP request and it returns an HTTP response.  Looks like your HTTP client asked for the response as JSON, but it could also ask for plain text or XML.

Your result is correct - this is exactly what Spring controller should be doing.

You need to read a little bit more about Spring web MVC.  You can create an HTML page template to render the data in the way you wish.

You could also create a React or Angular front end app that calls the Spring controller and renders the JSON that you got in an HTML page.

Spring web MVC would mean that the page is coupled with the controller as one app.

A React/Angular front end would keep it separate from the controller.  You'd have two deployments instead of one.

Comment: Thanks for this aswell, I actually ended up using thymeleaf rather then front end frameworks, but this might be usefull in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Thymeleaf view engine for HTML pages if building a Spring MVC application. https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Gradle dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
```

You can put HTML pages/templates under main/resources/templates. In your controller you can return a ModelAndView (org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView) object. See the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) for available methods.

I highly recommend Spring Boot for web applications, application backends, etc. Saves the tedious configuration of Spring and provides the tools needed to build an enterprise application adhering to industry best practices.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I ended up with. I only use Model to return. This was helpful aswell.